# OpenGl transparency not working despite setting up blend function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a half-transparent red rectangle in OpenGl. The problem is, that I all I get is a opaque red rectangle, no matter what transparency I set. I am calling the following lines right after window initialization:

```cpp
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
```

My shader looks like this:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
}
```

The result I get:
[image: Opaque red square]

The result I expect:
[image: Transparent red triangle]

Just in case if someone will think, that I'm trying to troll or something like that, the "expectation" has been done by simply turning the red value to 0.5. It has nothing to do with transparency.

EDIT: I used the edit to destroy the edit (solution in my answer below)

Comment: Do you clear the framebuffer by [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) in every frame or do you continuously blend the red quad with the red quad of the previous frame in the framebuffer?

Comment: I clear the display in the loop with `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`. I am quite new to Opengl, so I'm not sure what do you mean by
> continuosly blend the red quad with the framebuffer

Comment: If `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` is invoked in the render loop, it is fine.

Comment: It would be helpful if you extracted your edit into an actual answer to the question, so that other users can tell that it's already been answered. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Actual problem wasn't even related to OpenGl. Just a code error. I have no idea, how did I miss it before, but this is, how the window intializing function looked before:

```cpp
window* createWindow(int width, int height, const char* title, const char* flags[], size_t fcnt) {
    return new window(width, height, title, flags, fcnt);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
}
```

For those, who didn't notice: I'm trying to call functions after return statement.

The correct function is:

```cpp
window* createWindow(int width, int height, const char* title, const char* flags[], size_t fcnt) {
    window* newwnd = new window(width, height, title, flags, fcnt);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

    return newwnd;
}
```

Comment: It was impossible to find the answer by just seeing the code snippets in the question. Finally this is no OpenGL issue.